# 15 meter zinc gutter, flex enough to bend a little (0.5 degree)?

Tags: gutters, slope

I have a flat roof, ~ 150 m2. The roof is under a ~ 5 degree slope.

Since the roof is approx 15 meters long (by 10 meters wide), I was thinking to make (on the low side) the high point of the gutter in the *center* of the wall. Then install the drains on each side (125mm dia).

```
           drain          CENTER         drain
           (low)          (high)         (low)
             |--- 7500 mm --||-- 7500 mm --| 
             |                             |
        (0.5% drop)                   (0.5% drop)
```

I would like to use zinc gutters (½ round), but I'm a bit concerned how to connect these at the center.

If I buy a long piece of zinc gutter (~ 6-10 meter), would this by itself be *flex* enough so I can achieve a 0.5% drop/pitch? Or would I need to solder two parts in the center under an angle?

Thanks!

[image: Simple sketch]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. How much (linearly) is that rise in the middle? And, what do you mean by "the roof is under a ~ 5 degree slope"; is it a flat roof?

Comment: @DanielGriscom thanks! Yes a flat roof. Not sure how you call this. Its square but the front lays higher than the back (approx 5 degree). So water runs down natural atop the back side. The "diagram" resembles the back of the house.

Comment: The alternative, of course, is just to make a cut at the center and lap somewhat, sealing between. It'll be almost invisible from below.

Answer (score 1):

Galvanized steel will easily take a small strain like that. The normal yield strength of steel is not reached until total strain is 0.5% strain. That is ,it would need to be held in place to prevent "springback" at 0.5 strain.  However , 0.2 % is permanent strain ( no springback). Or , extreme case ,you bend it slightly ( I doubt that will be necessary).  If you want a 6 m ( about 20 ft) length with no seam you will need to use aluminum , not galvanized steel.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it is not clear on what direction your roof has a 5% slope.

For a 0.5% drop, that is only 6.5cm on each side. (7.5m * tan 0.5%) I think you will have no problem with the gutter flexing only 6.5cm over 7.5 meters.

Comment: sorry, I was not sure how you call it. Its' just a flat roof, but the front lays a bit higher.  Water will (naturally) run down to the back of the house. I don't think I can buy munch longer then 4-6 meter zinc, so I was hoping if I put the center off that piece in the middle, it would naturally flex enough. I added a simple drawing.

Comment: One nuance I didn’t think of earlier: if you use a straight piece of gutter and pull down both ends, you don’t end up with a constant 0.5% slope; you end up with 0.5% at the ends, 0% in the middle, and a varying amount of slope in between. This may or may not be acceptable to you.

Comment: thanks for the after thought! Good point. Do you have any idea how you would normally get the angle (at the center)? I tried searching, but all examples are tiny cutters like a only a few meters, and they just have the water run of to one side? Cut it and solder?